# Error passing required() Image as a prop

Tags: image, react-native, components

I have a file called data.js where I export an object, which one of its elements is an Image. This is how it looks:

```
var data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "Category": "Category Title",
    "Image": require("../images/comingsoon.png"),
    "Summary": ""
  },
```

And then in another component I import the data variable and I pass the data.Image to another component as a prop using FlatList.

```
<FlatList
   style={{margin:5}}
   numColumns={2}
   data={this.state.data}
   renderItem={({item}) => item}
/>
```

`item` looks like this:

```
<CategoryItem key={item.id} Image={item.Image} Category={item.Category}/>
```

And then I use the Image prop inside CategoryItem like so:

```
<Image source={this.props.item.Image} style={styles.CategoryImage}>
```

And this works perfectly!...
But I wanted to simply pass Item as a prop to CategoryItem like so:

```
<CategoryItem key={item.id} item={item}/>
```

And once inside CategoryItem, I would do:

```
  render(){
    const {Category, Image} = this.props.item;
```

And call the Image simply by doing

```
<Image source={Image} style={styles.CategoryImage}>
```

However, when I do that, the app crashes and it says that `Image` is a number.
[image: Screenshot of crash report]

After logging what `item` looks like, I found out that `require()`ing turns the image into a number[image: Console results of console.log(Image)], and it should work by simply passing it differently, it crashes. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you actually using RequireJS? If not, you should remove that tag because RequireJS is a specific product. If you are using RequireJS, then your question needs editing to give context explaining how you are using it (no, that single `require` call there is not enough) because there's no reason to believe that it is in fact a factor in your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the local variable `Image` is shadowing the component named `Image`.

Your code, simplified, might look something like this:

```
import { Image } from 'react-native';

class CategoryItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { Category, Image } = this.props;
    return <Image source={Image} />
  }
}
```

Instead of the `<Image />` declaration referring to the component as you'd expect, it refers to the `Image` prop.

This is easy to fix by renaming the variable:

```
class CategoryItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { Category, Image: imageSource } = this.props;
    return <Image source={imageSource} />
  }
}
```

The reason the error tells you the component is a `number` is a implementation detail of how the React Native asset imports work. When you import an image with `require('path.jpg')`, React Native assigns that image a unique numeric ID and returns that instead of a image path descriptor. This is beneficial for performance reasons, so instead of passing a descriptor over the native-javascript bridge for each render, it can pass over a number, which are cheaper to serialize and to marshall.

As a side note, it's a common React practice to declare your component props in `lowerCamelCase`, so instead of `<CategoryItem Image={}` /> you would have `<CategoryItem image={} />`. This is just a convention, but in this case it would have avoided this error.

Comment: Thanks for the great and clear explanation. I didn't realize my mistake.

Comment: Hey, I have a component and i pass an image as a prop and other props navigate and i want to take the image I passed as a prop in react-navigation, how i handle these? `<PopularFood
                img={require('../../assets/food-2.png')}
                navigate={() => {
                  this.props.navigation.navigate('Itme', {
                    image: this.props.img, // not work!!
                  });
                }}
              />` @jevakallio